# Firebase Analytics with Firestack in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-analytics

Some explanation about the project itself:
We are building an App in React Native for Android and IOS.
We would like to use Firebase as they provide a lot of great stuff.

Everything of Firebase is working in the App (remote config, database,storage, etc.), and a little bit of Analytics.
We created a small feedback component which puts data in the Firebase database (comments and star rating).

Now we also would like to show some data in the Analytics part.

We got User Properties setup accordingly, created Audiences and running 10+ devices and 10+ users to get data in Analytics.

We do get the basic stuff in, such as the main event. But all custom data we put in, wont show in the Dashboard.

The following code we have in a function thats get triggered every time feedback has been send.

```
firestack.analytics.logEventWithName('feedback', { 'screen': this.props.pageTitle });
firestack.analytics.logEventWithName('feedback_2', {
  'item_id': '1',
  'item_name': this.props.pageTitle,
  'item_category': 'category 1',
  'star_count': this.state.starCount
});
firestack.analytics.logEventWithName('view_item', {
  'item_id': '10',
  'item_name': this.props.pageTitle,
  'item_category': 'category 10',
  'star_count': this.state.starCount
});
```

Like said before, the main events (feedback, feedback_2 and view_item) are shown in Analytics, but all the custom data and parameters don't appear anywhere.

In Android Studio, the console log just shows the following for each event "Logging event view_item" or "Logging event feedback_2".

Do we miss something or do we need to expand the contract to Blaze to have BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of Firebase Analytics Developer Console will not display parameters of custom events:

> Custom parameters: Custom parameters are not represented directly in
>   your Analytics reports, but they can be used as filters in audience
>   definitions that can be applied to every report. Custom parameters are
>   also included in data exported to BigQuery if your app is linked to a
>   BigQuery project.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events